# Авторизация на сайте посредством Java

Tags: авторизация, java

Добрый день, не могли бы вы подсказать каким образом можно пройти авторизацию на удаленном сайте посредством **Java**.

Перепробовал все что нашел в Google. Но каждый раз после парсинга странички сайта она остается такой же как и до авторизации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо ХэшКод! :) Разобрался.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

try {
    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://www.somesite.ru/takelogin.php");

    List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "Yourname"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "Yourpasswd"));

    httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpost, responseHandler);
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(responseBody);
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

} finally {
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Теперь возник такой вопрос - Каким образом открыть другую страничку этого же сайта и не потерять статус авторизации на нем?...

Авторизовался я удачно, но как перейти на страницу http://www.somesite.ru/ololo и не потерять авторизацию?

Comment: Создавайте новый вопрос.